# How to use @DateTimeFormat in springboot in DTO?

Tags: spring-boot

In my Request DTO when I am trying to use pattern HHmm it's not working but HH:mm works.

```
public class RequestDTO {

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "HHmm")
    private LocalTime companyOfficeHoursStart;

}
```

Below is my MockMVC test:

```
String requestPayload = "{\"companyOfficeHoursStart\":\"1920\"}";
        RequestBuilder operation = post("/bookings").content(requestPayload)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
```

How can we use **HHmm** format ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring DateTimeFormat Configuration for java.time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871033/spring-datetimeformat-configuration-for-java-time)

Answer (score 1):

`@JsonFormat` is a Jackson annotation, with Jackson being used to serialize/deserialize POJOs to/from JSON. `@DateTimeFormat` is a Spring annotation, which is used for setting the format with which the date is saved to the database.

For your use case, you're trying to serialize/deserialize a POJO, so you need to use `@DateTimeFormat`.

Please see this thread for more information:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871033/spring-datetimeformat-configuration-for-java-time#:~:text=%40JsonFormat%20is%20a%20Jackson%20annotation,rendered%20in%20the%20JSP%20view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871033/spring-datetimeformat-configuration-for-java-time#:%7E:text=%40JsonFormat%20is%20a%20Jackson%20annotation,rendered%20in%20the%20JSP%20view).

Answer (score -1):

We need to use `@JsonFormat` when we want that fields of our DTO needs to be converted to JSON/XML using Jackson and `@DateTimeFormat` needs to be used when we want JSON to be converted in to field in DTO